# Can not scroll when add 2 CCScrollLayer in a layer

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, ccscrolllayer

I'm using CCScrollLayer files at here [CCScrollLayer](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x-extensions/tree/master/extensions/CCScrollLayer) for my cocos2d-x project (version 2.2.2).

I adapted them to make it can scroll vertically. And I got a problem: when I add two CCScrollLayer in a layer, I just can only scroll the last CCScrollLayer that are added.

Here is my code:

I add a layer that contains the two CCScrollLayer to a Scene

```
void ChooseMapScene::addSlidingLayers()
{
  mChooseCharacterLayer = createChooseCharaterLayer();
  mChooseCharacterLayer->setPosition(CCPointZero);
  mChooseCharacterLayer->setTouchEnabled(true);      
  this->addChild(mChooseCharacterLayer, GR_FOREGROUND);
}
```

I add SlideCharacter1 and SlideCharacter2 in a layer (chooseCharacterLayer) but just the SlideCharacter2 can scroll

```
CCLayer* ChooseMapScene::createChooseCharaterLayer()
{
  CCLayer* chooseCharacterLayer = CCLayer::create();
  CCArray* characterArr1 = createCharactersArray(CHARACTER_LEFT_LAYER_POS);
  CCArray* characterArr2 = createCharactersArray(CHARACTER_RIGHT_LAYER_POS);

  mSlideCharacter1 = CCScrollLayerVertical::nodeWithLayers(characterArr1, 0);
  chooseCharacterLayer->addChild(mSlideCharacter1, GR_FOREGROUND);

  mSlideCharacter2 = CCScrollLayerVertical::nodeWithLayers(characterArr2, 0);
  chooseCharacterLayer->addChild(mSlideCharacter2, GR_FOREGROUND);

  // I add SlideCharacter1 and SlideCharacter2 in a layer (chooseCharacterLayer) but just the SlideCharacter2 can scroll

  return chooseCharacterLayer;
}
```

.

```
CCArray* ChooseMapScene::createCharactersArray(CCPoint pPos)
{
  CCArray* characterArr = CCArray::createWithCapacity(NUMBER_CHARACTERS);
  for (int i = 1; i <= NUMBER_CHARACTERS; ++i)
  {
    CCLayer* characterLayer = CCLayer::create();

    CCSprite* character = CCSprite::create(CCString::createWithFormat("Images/Game/Object/c%i.png", i)->getCString());
    character->setPosition(pPos);
    characterLayer->addChild(character, GR_FOREGROUND, i);
    characterArr->addObject(characterLayer);
  }
  return characterArr;
}
```

Comment: Either of Scroll Layer scrolling when you swipe your finger or try to scroll?

Comment: I can't do anything(swipe or scroll) with SlideCharacter1, but with SlideCharacter2 i can scroll or swipe

Comment: Yes, it is possible that SlideCharacter1's touch delegate is not being called

Comment: So, how can i fix it? Any suggestion?

P/s: I think it *may be* SlideCharacter2 has overlap the SlideCharacter1, so i can't interact with SlideCharacter1. Is it correct?

Comment: check for swallowTouch bool in your touch dispatcher. It might be possible that swallowTouch value is set to FALSE. Can you please share CCScrollLayerVertical file?

Comment: yes, of course.It's here
[CCScrollLayerVertical.h](https://github.com/tranvictor/landlord/blob/horizontal-master/Classes/CCScrollLayerVertical.h)
[CCScrollLayerVertical.cpp](https://github.com/tranvictor/landlord/blob/horizontal-master/Classes/CCScrollLayerVertical.cpp)

Comment: Yes, Swallow touch value is set to false so it will not propagate touch to other touch delegate methods. So Enable swallowTouch in registerWithTouchDispatcher method.

Comment: So, I change the swallowTouch to true as below
`void CCScrollLayerVertical::registerWithTouchDispatcher()
{
  CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(this, kCCMenuHandlerPriority - 1, true);
}
`
Then i cant touch anything in the screen. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually call `SlideCharacter1`'s touch methods (began, cancelled, moved, ended) from `SlideCharacter2`'s touch methods to simulate the touches

Comment: Can you be more specific? 
I found that CCScrollLayer touch's method are all protected.
Can you give an example?